# WinCache caching incorrect CakePHP files

Tags: php, caching, cakephp-1.3

I have a bizarre problem with WinCache and it's possible this isn't the best forum. I checked SuperUser but there are 0 results regarding WinCache. Support seems to be weak throughout the web but at least SO has discussed it before.

I have a live and a development site on the same server (CakePHP framework, Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5, PHP 5.3, FastCGI, WinCache 1.1). Live site is on port 80 and dev on 81. IIS has two web sites, each pointing to a different root folder in Inetpub\wwwroot. Each site is run under a different application pool.

Some time after a change to the dev site the live site started erroring. After some painful debugging I found out that the following (totally lame) chain of events occurs:

1. Live PHP script loads as normal following GET request
2. Live PHP script POSTs **to itself** as normal following user selection
3. Dev PHP script handles POST request and errors when form parameters are not as expected.

If I inspect the WinCache properties through the web interface under port 80 (live site) I see the document root is Inetpub\wwwroot\Live - as expected. However, if I review the list of cached files under the file cache tab I see some files cached twice. Mouse-over tells me that one is from Inetpub\wwwroot\Dev and the other from Inetpub\wwwroot\Live.

How is this possible? Why is IIS using one in a GET request and another in POST? I know that CakePHP chooses which files to load based on a formatted URL, but the index.php file which handles routing is within Inetpub\wwwroot\Live, so presumably could never request a file in a different doc root. It seems to me that PHP asks IIS for a file, but IIS is losing its marbles when communicating with WinCache.

So far I can't see any way to disable WinCache for one site, but even if I could I probably wouldn't trust it anymore.

Any suggestions on this vexing issue will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have no Problems.

Try this:
Use Wincache 1.2 (Beta)

Dont use "." in the AppPool Name.

(Opt.) Create a ProcessUser for each AppPool.

Look for session files called "wincache_session_*" in the our session directory.

Copy the wincache.php from "[AppDir 86]\IIS[Wincache]\wincache.php" in each webdirectory
and open it over http.

Comment: I appreciate the input, but given that this problem exists and has caused real problems I would appreciate some comments on why you suggest the above steps, and how they might impact the problems I have seen. I'm currently not using WinCache as it's too risky - site configuration is handled by a PHP file so there is a risk of this problem putting dev data in the live database. If I were to use WinCache again and it still presented the same problems I might not see the evidence for a long time.